# Disable JS Interaction Temporarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the following function to operate in a way that prevents users from spamming the mouseenter, mouseleave function, so that they can only operate the mouseenter/leave function once the fade action is complete. How would I do that?

`$("#bocks").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#bocks2").fadeOut(); });
    $("#bocks").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#bocks2").fadeIn();

    });`

http://jsfiddle.net/x2qNZ/

Comment: Throttle/debounce might be more appropriate here?

Comment: I've started looking into throttle/debounce, and it seems exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var blocked = false;
function unblock() {
    blocked = false;
}
$("#bocks").mouseenter(function(){ 
   if (blocked) return;
   blocked = true;
   $("#bocks2").fadeOut(unblock); 
}); 
$("#bocks").mouseleave(function(){ 
   if (blocked) return;
   blocked = true;
   $("#bocks2").fadeIn(unblock);
});
```

You could also remove the event listeners and place it again in the unblock() function.

Answer (score 0):

FadeIn/Fade out have completion callbacks.

http://jsfiddle.net/x2qNZ/3/

I have updated the Fiddle to disable fadeIn if we are actively fadingOut.

```
var isFiring = false;
    $("#bocks").mouseenter(function(){
        isFiring = true;
        $("#bocks2").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            isFiring = false;
        }); 
    });
    $("#bocks").mouseleave(function(){
        if(!isFiring){
          $("#bocks2").fadeIn();
        } else {
           console.log('fire ignored');
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the updated fiddle

```
var mouseenterbusy = false;
var mouseleavebusy = false;
$("#bocks").mouseenter(function(){
    if (mouseenterbusy == true) {
        return;
    }
    mouseenterbusy = true;
    $("#bocks2").fadeOut(function (){
       mouseenterbusy = false;                     
    }); 
});
$("#bocks").mouseleave(function(){
    if (mouseleavebusy == true) {
        return;
    }
    mouseleavebusy = true;
    $("#bocks2").fadeIn(function (){
       mouseleavebusy = false;                     
    });     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2qNZ/5/